# TFS 2010 Powershell Get-TFSItemHistory returning oldest version and not the latest

Tags: powershell

In TFS 2010, using powershell

```
  Get-tfsItemHistory $path -server $servername
```

returns the oldest changeset and not the latest changeset. Is there anyway to get the latest changeset
Thanks
Nate

Comment: I can use the  Get-tfsItemHistory $path -server $servername - recurse  to get all changesets and find the latest, But is there a direct way to get the latest changeset

Answer (score 1):

```
  PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-tfsItemHistory $path -server $servername -All -recurse -stopafter 1 | select Owner ,
```

creationDate

That resolved my requirement